# Used Joined tables in select statment

Tags: sql, join, case

I was wondering if it is possible to use a bound joined table in a CASE statment when declaring a column in a select statment. I have included a simplified example of my problem in the snippet below.Any ideas? Thanks!

```
SELECT  M.MID 
    ,[Count] =  CASE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Refund R2 
            WHERE R2.RefundID = R.RefundID) = 1
                        THEN 'One'
                        ELSE 'Many'
                        END

FROM #temp T
JOIN Refund R ON R.RefundID = T.RefundID
```

The "WHERE R2.RefundID = R.RefundID says that the "R.RefundID cannot be bound.

Comment: If you take out the word CASE you have a valid query...

Comment: It seems like you need a CASE WHEN (for SQL Server at least)

Comment: What is the alias `R2` supposed to refer to? I don't see it anywhere else in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you could try a different approach:

```
SELECT
  M.MID, 
  [Count] = CASE COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY R.RefundID)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'One'
    ELSE 'Many'
  END
FROM #temp T
JOIN Refund R ON R.RefundID = T.RefundID
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad alias. You have an `R` but not an `R2`, which is referenced:

```
SELECT  M.MID 
        ,[Count] =  CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ReferralTypeKey R2
                               WHERE R2.RefundID = R.RefundID) = 1
                               THEN 'One'
                               ELSE 'Many'
                               END

FROM #temp T
JOIN Refund R ON R.RefundID = T.RefundID
```

Comment: Your are right copy error i fixed it here in the site but it doesnt work still

Comment: @Jbone - I also corrected the `CASE` syntax, which was incorrect.

Comment: @Jbone - can you clarify "Doesn't work"?  Is it the same error message?  What's the line number of the error indicate?